# RecyclerView binded to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, wrong row deleted when checked a checkbox

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I bind a `recyclerView` to `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, and set `OnClickListener` for checkboxes in `ViewHolder`.

My idea:
When a checkbox of a row is checked, the adapter will `getRef(clickedPosition)` and call `removeValue` to delete the row from Firebase database. After that, the `populateViewHolder` is called and the application will show the latest data from the database.

Problem:
If I delete from the bottom of the list upwards, there is no problem.
However, if randomly check checkboxes, seems the wrong row will be deleted, and sometimes even will have `NULL` position and cause the Android app crash.
I have Log the position, seems the position of checkboxes is not updated correctly after a row is deleted.

Here is my code:

```
public Firebase mRef;

// UI
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Task, MessageViewHolder> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_task);
   ...
   ...
   Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
   mRef = new Firebase("https://what-to-do-list.firebaseio.com/todoItems");

   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
   mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Task, MessageViewHolder>(
                    Task.class,
                    R.layout.custom_row_view,
                    MessageViewHolder.class,
                    mRef
            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder, Task t, int i) {

                    messageViewHolder.mText.setText(t.getName());
                    messageViewHolder.chkBox.setTag(i);

                    messageViewHolder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                            int clickedPos = ((Integer) cb.getTag()).intValue();


                            Log.v("POSITION: ", String.valueOf(clickedPos));
                            adapter.getRef(clickedPos).removeValue();
                        }
                    });
                }      
            };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public static class MessageViewHolder
        extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mText;
    CheckBox chkBox;

    public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
        chkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.task_chkbox);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your populateViewHolder to:

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder, Task t, int i) {

    final DatabaseReference ref = getRef(i);
    messageViewHolder.mText.setText(t.getName());
    messageViewHolder.chkBox.setTag(ref);

    messageViewHolder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            String key = cb.getTag().getKey();

            adapter.getRef(key).removeValue();
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, on deleting an element in recycler view, positions of the remaining elements are not getting updated. So, using "i" as an index is wrong. Instead, use:

```
messageViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()
```